# How to clean long neglected, partially sunken landscape rocks

Tags: weed-control, landscaping, hard-landscape, rocks

Not sure if there is really an easy method, but here is our situation with two pictures. It is a relatively large area (~1100 sq. ft.) inside a vinyl fence, so not easy to get heavy machinery in. I also built a box frame with hardware cloths like [this setup](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/14145/29602), but an hour's back breaking work clears perhaps only 10 sq. ft. area since many of the rocks have sunken and mixed with the soil/dirt.

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you just have to bite the bullet. Everything is on the table. A fence is just a fence and can be removed and replaced, or not. Heavy concrete pavers can be removed and replaced, or not. With the pavers and the fence out of the way, a small digger/backhoe on tracks could take the stony soil out, be trucked away to someplace where fill for a foundation is needed, and replaced with good soil. Replace fence and other features as required. It is the long way around, but gets the job done.

Comment: Yeah, I was more and more convinced that perhaps this was the only way out..